# Can't connect Google Calendar API to my python project

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I used to be able to connect them. Then I created a new account, since I wanted to access a new calendar.
I deleted the older credential.json file, the client_secret and the pickle file.

I opened my new google account, downloaded a new credential file and copied it to my project directory.

When I run the code and it prompt me to the google log in , and I fill the blanks, this is what I get :

[image]

My code worked with no problem with my old crendentials, anyone can tell me what's up?

Thank you

Comment: Did you set-up a new project, configure the outh screen, enable the calendar API and implement an uthUTL? See [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php). Show your code for better troubleshooting.

Comment: may be you gotta see your redirected url's.